# python enumerate out of range when looping through a file

Tags: python, python-itertools, enumerate

I have a file of paths called `test.txt`

```
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_2_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002T_2_Clean.fastq.gz
```

Notice that the number of lines is even and always even, my final goal is to parse this file and create a new one looping through these paths on a two by two basis. I am trying `enumerate` function but this will not parse two by two. Furthermore, I'm going out of range because indexing the way I'm doing is wrong. It would also be great if someone could tell me how to index properly with `enumerate`.

```
 with open('./src/test.txt') as f:
    for index,line in enumerate(f):
        sample = re.search(r'pfg[\dGT]+',line)
        sample_string = sample.group(0)
        #print(sample_string)
        print('{{"name":"{0}","readgroup":"{0}","platform_unit":"{0}","fastq_1":"{1}","fastq_2":"{2}","library":"{0}"}},'.format(sample_string,line,line[index+1]))
```

The result is something like this:

```
{"name":"pfg001G","readgroup":"pfg001G","platform_unit":"pfg001G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"g","library":"pfg001G"},
{"name":"pfg001G","readgroup":"pfg001G","platform_unit":"pfg001G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"r","library":"pfg001G"},
{"name":"pfg001T","readgroup":"pfg001T","platform_unit":"pfg001T","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"o","library":"pfg001T"},
{"name":"pfg001T","readgroup":"pfg001T","platform_unit":"pfg001T","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"u","library":"pfg001T"},
{"name":"pfg002G","readgroup":"pfg002G","platform_unit":"pfg002G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"p","library":"pfg002G"},
{"name":"pfg002G","readgroup":"pfg002G","platform_unit":"pfg002G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"s","library":"pfg002G"},
{"name":"pfg002T","readgroup":"pfg002T","platform_unit":"pfg002T","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/","library":"pfg002T"},
{"name":"pfg002T","readgroup":"pfg002T","platform_unit":"pfg002T","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002T_2_Clean.fastq.gz","fastq_2":"c","library":"pfg002T"},
```

Clearly the indexation is wrong since it's going through every element of my path that is `g` `r` etc instead of printing the next path. For the first iteration the next path printed should be: `"fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_2_Clean.fastq.gz"`.

I believe the problem itself can be tackled with `itertools` more elegantly I just don't know how to do it. Would also be great if someone could tell me if an indexation with enumerate could also work.

Comment: use `enumerate(f.readlines())`

Comment: @sahasrara62 An open file in text mode is an iterator over the lines already. Your code will just add an intermediate list and use extra memory.

Comment: @KlausD. oh, didn't know that, thanks for correcting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you are trying to access the data from the second line of the pair *before* you have read it. Additionally you can not access the second line with `line[index + 1]` because that refers to a character in the current line, not the next line which hasn't yet been read.

So you need to keep track of pairs of lines. You can use the index provided by `enumerate()` to determine whether the current line is the first (because it is an even number) or the second (because it's odd). Store the name and path for fastq_1 when you read the first line. Only write the output on the second line. Like this:

import re

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        if index % 2 == 0:      # even, so this is the first line of a pair
            name = re.search(r'pfg[\dGT]+',line).group(0)
            fastq_1 = line.rstrip()
        else:                   # odd, so second line. Emit result
            fastq_2 = line.rstrip()
            print('{{"name":"{0}","readgroup":"{0}","platform_unit":"{0}","fastq_1":"{1}","fastq_2":"{2}","library":"{0}"}},'.format(name, fastq_1, fastq_2))
```

`line.rstrip()` is required to remove the trailing new line character at the end of each line.

Comment: nice it works, I first did not understand how come the regex implementation applies to all the loop since the `else` part has no regex. But it seems like the `name` variable is stored on the very first if statement which evaluates to `True`  and then the first `Else` which evaluates to `True` can already see the object `name`. is that right ?

Comment: @alex: that's right. As a suggestion, it would be better if you created a dictionary with the various items, and then use `json.dump()` to output ir.

Answer (score 1):

@mhawke already provided a good solution, but to give another approach, "looping through these ... on a two by two basis" can be done with the [`more_itertools.chunked` function](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) from the more_itertools library or with the [`grouper()` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the Python manual.

This also gives options for what should happen when the last line is an odd one; whether that should raise an error or pair it with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider that when you're assigning index to variable, you're getting the index character of that string not the indexation of it.

What you can do is to assign th e file to a list then get the index location so, you can switch between line as you want.

Still don't understand point, **do you want to switch between lines in both `fastq_1` and `fastq_2` or you each path be according to its key?**

**Code Syntax**

```
with open(path) as f:
    lis = list(f)
    for index, line in enumerate(lis):
        try:
            sample = re.search(r'pfg[\dGT]+',line)
            sample_string = sample.group(0)

            print(f'{{"name":"{sample_string}","readgroup":"{sample_string}","platform_unit":"{sample_string}","fastq_1":"{line}","fastq_2":"{lis[index+1]}","library":"{sample_string}"}},')
        except IndexError:
                break
```

**Output**

```
{"name":"pfg001G","readgroup":"pfg001G","platform_unit":"pf
g001G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/Leung
SY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Ta
rgeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","library":"pfg001G"},
{"name":"pfg001G","readgroup":"pfg001G","platform_unit":"pf
g001G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/Leung
SY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","library":"pfg001G"},
{"name":"pfg001T","readgroup":"pfg001T","platform_unit":"pf
g001T","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/Leung
SY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","library":"pfg001T"},
{"name":"pfg001T","readgroup":"pfg001T","platform_unit":"pf
g001T","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/Leung
SY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg001T_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","library":"pfg001T"},
{"name":"pfg002G","readgroup":"pfg002G","platform_unit":"pf
g002G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/Leung
SY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","library":"pfg002G"},
{"name":"pfg002G","readgroup":"pfg002G","platform_unit":"pf
g002G","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002G_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","library":"pfg002G"},
{"name":"pfg002T","readgroup":"pfg002T","platform_unit":"pfg002T","fastq_1":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/Leung
SY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002T_1_Clean.fastq.gz
","fastq_2":"/groups/cgsd/javed/validation_set/LeungSY_Targeted_SS-190528-01a/Clean/pfg002T_2_Clean.fastq.gz
","library":"pfg002T"},

[Program finished]
```